# How to upload WhatsApp status using intent of an Android app?

Tags: video, android-intent, upload, share, whatsapp

How can we use intent.packageName(“com.whatsapp”) to share/upload an image/video to WhatsApp status in an Android application using Koltin or Java ?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsapp image caption");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: Hi, please describe your problem better. What have you tried? Whats is the problem? Do you have any code to illustrate the issue? Otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to share an image using an intent to whatsapp status. But, its only showing option for sharing to contacts only.

Comment: did you get an answer to do it?, the app of TikTok is able to show an option to share it bt WhatsApp status, IDK how they did that.

Comment: @SYEDASADKAZMI did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a direct way to share to Whatsapp Status.

Just looked into the flow of how Tiktok does their uploads to Whatsapp status.

First, the file is downloaded locally, then the file path is shared via an intent targeting `com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.contact.picker.ContactPicker` URI.
Once on the target screen, the user can then choose to share on their status or to specific contacts from the list.